# Size commands do not work in mathmode

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\wedge{\small\wedge}{\tiny\wedge}$
\end{document}
```

All the `\wedge`s have the same size...

[image]

Comment: I don't think `\small` works in math mode at all.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

`\small` and `\tiny` are *text* font macros (just like `\large`, `\huge`, ...). You most likely received the following font warnings in your `.log` file:

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Command \small invalid in math mode on input line 3.

LaTeX Font Warning: Command \tiny invalid in math mode on input line 3.
```

Inside math mode, in order to use a different (smaller) font, you could/should use `\scriptstyle` or `\scriptscriptstyle`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\wedge{\small\wedge}{\tiny\wedge}$\par
$\wedge{\scriptstyle\wedge}{\scriptscriptstyle\wedge}$
\end{document}
```

`\scriptstyle` denotes the font size of super-/subscripts, while `\scriptscriptstyle` denotes the font size for super-/subscripts of super-/subscripts. Thereafter (higher scripting), the font size remains at `\scriptscriptsize`. See

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$x\ x^x\ x^{x^x}\ x^{x^{x^x}}\ x^{x^{x^{x^x}}}$
\end{document}
```

That's why there's a suggestion to use `\scalebox` (and possibly some height adjustment using `\raisebox`) - it allows you to have a little more variation in the fonts in smaller/larger sized.

Comment: I find `\scalebox` a good solution for my problem, which may be different from the original question...

Answer (score 16):

use

```
 $\wedge$\small$\wedge$\tiny$\wedge$\normalsize
```

Comment: or `$\wedge${\small$\wedge$\tiny$\wedge$}` so that it's not necessary to return explicitly to `\normalsize`, since that may or may not actually be the current size (say, in a footnote).

Comment: @barbarabeeton: yes, you're right. As usual :-)

Comment: Can this technique be transferred to environments like `equation`?

Comment: @bluenote10: try it ... ;-)

Comment: @Herbert: I did and I failed :). That is why I'm asking whether there is a trick to "temporarily leave" the equation environment to achieve the same.

Comment: give an example of what you did.

Answer (score 7):

Whenever you want to choose to have a small-sized equation in math mode, I would suggest the following

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}    
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}    
\begin{document}    
\[ 3+3=\text{\footnotesize{\(x^2-13 =\)} \tiny{\( y^3-26 \)} } \]    
\end{document}
```

Just be careful with parenthesis and spacing!