# Small labels with proof.sty

Tags: logic, proof-package

Is it possible to obtain small labels with `proof.sty`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german,english,italian]{babel}
\usepackage{easylist}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,varwidth,bussproofs,syllogism, mathrsfs, proof}
\begin{document}
     $$\infer[\wedge I]
          {(A \wedge B)}
          {A & B}
     \qquad
     \infer[\to E]
          {B}
          {(A \to B) & A}
     $$
\end{document}
```

I tried to use `\small`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) as always on this site please provide full minimal examples. For example, I have no idea where `\infer` comes from.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry, I edited my example putting a preamble. Well comand `\infer` is a comand of proof.sty package.

Comment: the presence of an unmatched `$$` just before `\end{document}` indicates that this isn't complete, and isn't going to compile.  (not being familiar with the `proof` package, i can't offer any more intelligent suggestion.)

Comment: There's no specific connexion to the `proof` package: you're just trying to display math in a smaller font, that you're doing it in a `proof` environment is irrelevant. Just have a look at [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88646/34551).

Comment: Ok, I flagged your question as a duplicate of that question. If you want to address someone, put a `@` in front of his/her username. Otherwise they won't know you answered their comment. On a side note, I strongly recommed you to use the [`ebproof` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ebproof) to draw proof trees.