# make smaller some relation in math environment

Tags: fontsize

I wrote the code below, but I want to make smaller the  `\left\vert‎\left(‎\dfrac{1}{16},‎\dfrac{1}{16}‎\right) ‎‎\right‎‎‎\rangle_{1,2}`

how should I do that?

```
    \documentclass{article} ‎‎
    ‎\usepackage{amsmath}  ‎‎
    ‎\begin{document}

    ‎\begin{align}‎
    \notag &\sum_{\substack{ w,n=‎-\infty‎ \\ N,‎\bar{N}‎}}^{‎\infty‎} ‎‎\langle ‎N,‎\bar{N},w,n‎\mid \,g‎‎\, ‎q^{L_{0}}‎\bar{q}\,^{‎\bar{L}_{0}} \mid ‎N,‎\bar{N},w,n ‎\rangle \\[2ex]
    &‎‎\alpha‎_{-1/2}^{2} \,  \left\vert‎\left(‎\dfrac{1}{16},‎\dfrac{1}{16}‎\right) ‎‎\right‎‎‎\rangle_{1,2}
    \end{align}‎

\end{document}‎‎‎
```

Comment: `align` mustn't be used inside of `equation` Why do you add them together? What do you mean by smaller? Smaller font?

Comment: @ LaRiFaRi, yes smaller font

Comment: Don't use `\Big`

Comment: `\tnify` has no effect in math mode.

Comment: @ egreg, I do what you say but it doesn't seem beautiful

Comment: @ Bernard, what should I do?

Comment: Bernard was having a typo, he meant `\tiny`. See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88646 in order to read about the correct syntax for smaller fonts. As egreg says, you should not use `\Big` when you want something to be smaller. Do the tweaking of parantheses in the end use `\bigl(` `\bigr)` and alike. `\dfrac` is redundant here, you can use `\frac` as you are already in displaystyle. Taking `dfrac` here seems strange as you are explicitly asking for a smaller solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really clear what you want to get; note that `\dfrac` makes *big* fractions notwithstanding the current math style. If you want small fractions in an `align` environment, use `\tfrac`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{207}
\begin{aligned}
&\sum_{\substack{w,n=-\infty\\N,\bar{N}}}^{\infty}
   \langle N,\bar{N},w,n\mid gq^{L_{0}}
\bar{q}^{\,\bar{L}_{0}}\mid N,\bar{N},w,n\rangle\\[2ex]
&\alpha_{-1/2}^{2}\bigl|\bigl(\tfrac{1}{16},\tfrac{1}{16}\bigr)\bigr\rangle_{1,2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Don't add random `\,` commands; the best for `\bar{q}^{xyz}` is

```
\bar{q}^{\,xyz}
```

instead of `\bar{q}\,^{xyz}`. Try and see the difference.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that, it will look ugly. Here is a compromise:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}‎\label{207}‎‎‎
    ‎\begin{aligned}‎
    \sum_{\mathclap{{\substack{ w,n=‎-\infty‎ \\ N,‎\bar{N}‎}}}}^{\infty} &\langle ‎N,‎\bar{N},w,n‎\mid \,g‎‎\, ‎q^{L_{0}}‎\bar{q}\,^{‎\bar{L}_{0}} \mid ‎N,‎\bar{N},w,n ‎\rangle \\
    &‎‎\langle\alpha‎_{-1/2}^{2} \mid (\tfrac{1}{16},‎\tfrac{1}{16}) \rangle^{}_{1,2}
    \end{aligned}‎
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If the second line is less important, it should not be set in the same equation but in the following text or in an unnumbered equation or alike.

Comment: @ laRiFaRi, I think I don't type \dfrac , I should type \tfrac. am I right?

Comment: @FarhadRazi That would be my recommendation. Change of font size is a bad typographical choice in most cases.