# Two arrows sharing a single point as target and initial are not lie in same straight-line in tikz picture

Tags: tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

I am currently running the following code:

```
    \pdfminorversion=4
\documentclass[]{article}


\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{adjustbox}



\begin{document}




$$\adjustbox{scale=1,center}{%
\begin{tikzcd}
\large 0               & \large 0               & \large 0               & \large 0                                 & \large 0                                  & \large 0                                  & \large 0                                  & \large 0                                  & \large 0 & \large 0 & \large 0 \\
\large 0               & \large 0               & \large 0               & \large 0                                 & \large 0                                  & \large 0                                  & \large 0                                  & \large 0                                  & \large 0 & \large 0 & \large 0 \\
\large 0               & \large 0               & \large 0               & {\large^\text{I}E^3_{4,1}} \arrow[rrruu] & {\large ^\text{I}E^3_{3,1}} \arrow[rrruu] & {\large ^\text{I}E^3_{2,1}} \arrow[rrruu] & {\large ^\text{I}E^3_{1,1}} \arrow[rrruu] & \large 0                                  & \large 0 & \large 0 & \large 0 \\
\large 0               & \large 0               & \large 0               & \large 0                                 & {\large ^\text{I}E^3_{3,0}} \arrow[rrruu] & {\large ^\text{I}E^3_{2,0}} \arrow[rrruu] & {\large ^\text{I}E^3_{1,0}} \arrow[rrruu] & {\large ^\text{I}E^3_{0,0}} \arrow[rrruu] & \large 0 & \large 0 & \large 0 \\
\large 0 \arrow[rrruu] & \large 0 \arrow[rrruu] & \large 0 \arrow[rrruu] & \large 0 \arrow[rrruu]                   & \large 0                                  & \large 0                                  & \large 0                                  & \large 0                                  & \large 0 & \large 0 & \large 0 \\
\large 0               & \large 0 \arrow[rrruu] & \large 0 \arrow[rrruu] & \large 0 \arrow[rrruu]                   & \large 0 \arrow[rrruu]                    & \large 0                                  & \large 0                                  & \large 0                                  & \large 0 & \large 0 & \large 0
\end{tikzcd}
}$$ 

\end{document}
```

It gives me following picture:

[image]

So you can see that initials and targets of arrow are correct, but two arrows sharing a single point as target and initial are not lie in same straight-line, i.e. to say picture is a kind of horrible. Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a lot of things going on. First of all, you have 300 (more or less :-) ) [warnings that `\large` do nothing in math mode,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88646/size-commands-do-not-work-in-mathmode) so get rid of it.

Then, there is a missing `\usepackage{}` for the `\text` command, which gives an error (why do you use it? it's just a number...)

Moreover, in LaTeX [you should never use `$$` for equations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503/why-is-preferable-to).

The main problem is because your cells in the diagram have different sizes, and so the "anchors" where the arrows point move around. One solution is to fix the sizes of the cells with `\tikzcdset{cells={text width=2.2em, text height=1em, text depth=0.4em}}` (you have to play with the numbers).

Finally, I have this:

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\tikzcdset{cramped, cells={text width=2.2em, text height=1em, text depth=0.4em}}
\adjustbox{width=\textwidth, center}{
\begin{tikzcd}
 0               &  0               &  0               &  0                                 &  0                                  &  0                                  &  0                                  &  0                                  &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
 0               &  0               &  0               &  0                                 &  0                                  &  0                                  &  0                                  &  0                                  &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
 0               &  0               &  0               & {^\text{I}E^3_{4,1}} \arrow[rrruu] & { ^\text{I}E^3_{3,1}} \arrow[rrruu] & { ^\text{I}E^3_{2,1}} \arrow[rrruu] & { ^\text{I}E^3_{1,1}} \arrow[rrruu] &  0                                  &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
 0               &  0               &  0               &  0                                 & { ^\text{I}E^3_{3,0}} \arrow[rrruu] & { ^\text{I}E^3_{2,0}} \arrow[rrruu] & { ^\text{I}E^3_{1,0}} \arrow[rrruu] & { ^\text{I}E^3_{0,0}} \arrow[rrruu] &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
 0 \arrow[rrruu] &  0 \arrow[rrruu] &  0 \arrow[rrruu] &  0 \arrow[rrruu]                   &  0                                  &  0                                  &  0                                  &  0                                  &  0 &  0 &  0 \\
 0               &  0 \arrow[rrruu] &  0 \arrow[rrruu] &  0 \arrow[rrruu]                   &  0 \arrow[rrruu]                    &  0                                  &  0                                  &  0                                  &  0 &  0 &  0
\end{tikzcd}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

which compiles *without errors* to:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works.